# FireFox not uninstalling on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, uninstall, apt

I am a Google Chrome user, and I notice that new Linux distributions always come pre-installed with FireFox.

Whenever I try to uninstall, I get this:

```
sudo apt remove --purge firefox firefoxdriver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer             

required:
  phantomjs python-easyprocess python-fuzzywuzzy python-levenshtein
  python-pyvirtualdisplay python-qt4reactor python-selenium
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr iceweasel
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix | otf-stix mozplugger
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  eyewitness* firefox* firefoxdriver*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr iceweasel
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

(Note the `The following NEW packages will be installed:` section)

I was wondering if there was any way to uninstall this?

Thanks

EDIT:

Output of `dpkg -l | grep fox`

```
dpkg -l | grep fox
ii  firefox                                   52.0.2-1                             
    amd64        Mozilla Firefox web browser
ii  firefoxdriver                             2.53.2-3                             
    amd64        Firefox WebDriver support
ii  owasp-mantra-ff                           0.9-1kali1                           
    amd64        Web application security testing framework built on top of Firefox
ii  volafox                                   0.8-1kali0                           
    all          Memory analyzer for Mac OS X & BSD
ii  xul-ext-noscript                          2.9.0.14-1                           
    all          permissions manager for Firefox
ii  xul-ext-useragentswitcher                 0.7.3-3                              
    all          Firefox addon that allows the user to choose user agents
```

Synaptic package manager:
[image: Synaptic]

After agreeing to removal:

```
sudo apt remove --purge firefox-esr iceweasel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer 
required:
  phantomjs python-easyprocess python-fuzzywuzzy python-levenshtein
  python-pyvirtualdisplay python-qt4reactor python-selenium
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  firefox
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix | otf-stix mozplugger
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox-esr* iceweasel*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 10.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

(Note the `The following NEW packages will be installed:` section)

Output of `apt-cache depends firefox`:

```
apt-cache depends firefox
firefox
  Depends: libatk1.0-0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo-gobject2
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libdbus-1-3
  Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2
  Depends: libevent-2.0-5
  Depends: libffi6
  Depends: libfontconfig1
  Depends: libfreetype6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
  Depends: libhunspell-1.4-0
  Depends: libjsoncpp1
  Depends: libpango-1.0-0
  Depends: libstartup-notification0
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: libvpx4
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libx11-xcb1
  Depends: libxcb-shm0
  Depends: libxcb1
  Depends: libxcomposite1
  Depends: libxdamage1
  Depends: libxext6
  Depends: libxfixes3
  Depends: libxrender1
  Depends: libxt6
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: fontconfig
    fontconfig:i386
  Depends: procps
    procps:i386
  Depends: debianutils
    debianutils:i386
  Depends: libsqlite3-0
  Conflicts: <j2re1.4>
  Conflicts: <pango-graphite>
  Breaks: <xul-ext-torbutton>
 |Suggests: fonts-stix
  Suggests: <otf-stix>
    fonts-stix
  Suggests: fonts-lmodern
  Suggests: mozplugger
 |Suggests: libgssapi-krb5-2
  Suggests: <libkrb53>
  Suggests: libcanberra0
```

Comment: What happens after you continue and it finishes? Are there any firefoxes left installed? May want to try a gui-like package manager, synaptic or aptitude too. And what packages are installed now anyway? Could check with `dpkg -l > packages-file` and look for "fox" stuff

Answer (score 0):

An overzealous package maintainer made the decision that you must have either `firefox` or `iceweasal` installed so as to be able to access web-based interfaces such as CUPS.  Go ahead and continue removing `firefox`and `firefoxdriver` Then just remove the newly installed `firefox-esr` and `iceweasal`.

Comment: It just loops, asking me to install firefox again

Comment: Sounds like you have some packages installed which have a hard dependency on `firefox`.  To see a list of such dependents, try `apt-cache depends firefox`

Comment: I  believe you mean **rdepends**, not *depends*.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae. You are correct.  Thanks for reporting the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt remove firefox-esr iceweasel firefox dolphin epiphany-browser
```

Try to avoid all the options given by the maintainer. Or if the `chromium` package is exist in your repo, just install it first.